# Restore DD Image of Bootcamp Windows to OSX

Tags: partition, osx, dd, restore

I made a DD image of my bootcamp partition before I wiped my computer. I restored with Time Machine and everything is great but I can't seem to get my running bootcamp partition back to a running state.

I created a FAT32 that was a little larger than the NTFS Bootcamp DD image via Disk Utility so that the GPT table would have an entry to a Microsoft basic data partition large enough to hold the image's contents.

I then DD'd the image to /dev/disk0sX partition device to write everything out to the new partition. OSX can read the file table because I can get at all of the files including the Windows system files.

However, when I go to reboot, the Bootcamp partition doesn't show up as a bootable option and when I got to "Startup Disk" in system preferences and force a boot to the Bootcamp partition, it says no operating system found or no boot device.

I didn't think the NTFS table would have anything screwy with it besides it not reading the full size of the partition. The LBA address should be relative to the start of the partition so I didn't think that should matter.

Even though it's a GPT partition, would the partition ID of the Bootcamp partition being a FAT32 partition type ID (0xb) instead of NTFS in the MBR affect it's bootability?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this image on the hard drive and bootable again?